# Handle exception thrown from listener method in f:ajax onevent function

Tags: jsf, exception

I am trying to handle a situation where an exception is thrown (Intentional in example) from my backing bean method that is being executed via ajax listener and I would like to handle it by displaying a [toastr message](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) stating that an error occurred with the request. My thought was that I could set a boolean within my bean when the exception is caught and then I would be able to pass that boolean into the onevent function to determine the type of toast message to display.

The problem is that at the time the onevent function is run, the boolean passed in has not been updated until the ajax has run at least twice (value is false on first call, then true on second call). It acts as if the onevent method runs it's cycle (For the 3 stages) and THEN updates the backing bean boolean. Is there a way in which this could work or am I simply not able to do this. I am aware of the [OmniFaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) but I would like to handle the exception in a more graceful manner using toast messages provided through [toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html). How can I get it so that when the listenerMethod throws an exception I can run a different set of javascript to display the correct information?

### Backing Bean

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
@Data
public class ExampleBean implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private Boolean ajaxError;

  public void initialize() {
    log.debug("Initialized Bean");
    ajaxError = false;
  }

  public void listenerMethod() {
    ajaxError = false;
    try {
      // method logic... throw intentional exception for now
      throw new Exception();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      ajaxError = true;
    }
  }
```

### XHTML

```
<h:commandLink id="ajax-link">
  <h:outputText value="Ajax Link" />
  <f:ajax listener="#{exampleBean.listenerMethod()}"
    render="Ids..."
    onevent="function(data) { ajaxEvent(data, '#{exampleBean.ajaxError}') }" />
</h:commandLink>
```

### JavaScript

```
function ajaxEvent = function(data, ajaxError) {
    var status = data.status;
    var title = 'Title';
    var message = 'Description message';

    console.log("AjaxError: " + ajaxError);
    switch (status) {
    case 'begin':
        // logic...
        break;
    case 'complete':
        // other logic...
        break;
    case 'success':
        if (ajaxError === 'true') {
            title = 'Error';
            message = 'An error occurred. Please try again later.';
            toastr['error'](message, title);
        } else {
            title = 'Success';
            message = 'Successful. No Exceptions Thrown.';
            toastr['success'](message, title);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```